# Retrieve number of messages in smart mailbox in Mail.app

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I'd like to retrieve the number of messages in a given smart mailbox in Mail.app.

Basically, I'd like to modify the [Übersicht](https://github.com/felixhageloh/uebersicht) *Unread mail count* widget (available [here](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht-widgets/)) to show the number of messages (both read and unread) in a smart mailbox I created.

The current code used in the widget is:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Mail" to set unreadCount to unread count of inbox
```

The biggest problem seems to be referencing the smart mailbox.

Comment: You can not reference the smart mailboxes through applescript. They are not actually objects. They are just custom spotlight views.